# Стандартные права при определении свой модели пользователя Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-model

При определении своей модели пользователя, наследуя от класса AbstractUser, как я понимаю вся функциональность аутентификации и разграничения прав должна полностью наследоваться от абстрактного класса пользователя, но при входе в админку, в разделе пользователи в пункте права пользователя отсутствует правая, вторая колонка, куда из первой добавляются права на пользователя. В чем может быть проблема?
Подскажите, если кто знает

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    filial = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Филиал')
    user_root_dir = models.CharField(max_length=218, verbose_name='Имя корневой папки пользователя')
```

В settings.py `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'`